# Prevent Facebook login from remounting the app

Tags: reactjs, facebook, react-native, facebook-sdk-4.x

There seems to be an issue with my implementation of the Facebook login for `react-native`

When I click on "Log in with the Facebook app" it opens the facebook app, then when I click "Continue" it reopens my app but it performs a remount. Part of my logic is to open another modal after that for some extra information from the user but calling `this.setState()` in the callback from the facebook login gives a `Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. And I can't seem to figure out how to get around this.

```
facebookLogin = async () => {
  let result;
  try {
    this.setState({
      loggingInWithFacebook: true
    }) 
    LoginManager.setLoginBehavior('native');
    result = await LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']);
  } catch (nativeError) {
    this.setState({
      loggingInWithFacebook: false
    })
    this.props.dispatch(openSnackBar({
      message: "There was an error opening facebook to login"
    }))
  }
  if (result.isCancelled) {
    this.setState({
      loggingInWithFacebook: false
    })
  } else {
    this.FBGraphRequest('first_name, last_name, id, email', this.FBLoginCallback);
  }
}
FBGraphRequest = async (fields, callback) => {
  const accessData = await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
  const infoRequest = new GraphRequest('/me', {
    accessToken: accessData.accessToken,
    parameters: {
      fields: {
        string: fields
      }
    }
  }, callback);
  new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(infoRequest).start();
}
FBLoginCallback = async (error, result) => {
  if (error) {
    this.setState({
      loggingInWithFacebook: false
    });
  } else {
    const {id, picture, ...rest} = result
    this._handleSocialLogin({...rest, facebook: id})
  }
}
_handleSocialLogin = (data) => {
  this.props.dispatch(socialLogin(data)).then(res => {
    this.props.dispatch(getGroups()).then(res => {
      this.setState({
        loggingInWithFacebook: false,
        loggingInWithGoogle: false
      })
      AsyncStorage.getItem('onBoarded').then((res)=> {
        if (res === 'true') {
          this.props.navigation.navigate("Map")
        } else {
          this.props.navigation.navigate("OnBoarding")
        }
      })
    }).catch(err => console.log(err.response.body))
  }).catch(err => {
    if (err.err === 'not found') {
      this.setState({
        enterPhoneModalVisible: true,
        socialData: data
      })
    } else {
      this.props.dispatch(
        openSnackBar({
          message: "There was an error logging in, please try again"
        })
      );
      this.setState({
        loggingInWithFacebook: false,
        loggingInWithGoogle: false
      })
    }
  })
}
```

EDIT:

My Appdelegate looks like this

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
```

In my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
return [RCTLinkingManager application:application
               continueUserActivity:userActivity
                 restorationHandler:restorationHandler];

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

  BOOL handledFB = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
    openURL:url
    sourceApplication:sourceApplication
    annotation:annotation
  ];

  BOOL handledRCT = [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];

  return handledFB || handledRCT;
```

EDIT 2:

I seem to have gotten it to work by changing my `openUrl` to the following

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                 openURL:url
                                       sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                              annotation:annotation
   ] || [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
}
```

Any idea why this works?

EDIT 3:

I'm still getting a `Login Failed` error randomly and there doesn't seem to be any definitive way to cause this to happen it just happens sometimes and then trying to login again right after it usually goes through